# How garbage collector detects garbage?

Tags: java, garbage, collectors

Can someone explain me with simple words how a JAVA garbage collector understands which part of memory is a ''garbage''?

I know what a garbage collector is actually doing but how identifies the ''garbages''?

Comment: What do you understand from your Google search?

Comment: Garbage is everything except what you're still referencing from your threads.

Comment: http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Java Virtual Machine, all data ist typed, which means the JVM can distinguish references from other data. Being able to distinguish references from other data is an almost necessary requirement for garbage collection to be possible.

The garbage collector traverses the heap, the stack and the constant pool, searching for references. Normally, all referenced objects are marked. Then the marked objects are traversed for references, and the referenced objects are in turn marked.

When there are no non-followed references left, you can be sure that all objects that are not marked are no longer accessible and can be disposed.

This is probably the most basic form of garbage collection, called a mark-and-sweep garbage collector.

Note that the Java standard does not require the existence of a garbage collector. A JVM implemententing the standard could as well never free any memory.

Comment: thanks,you ansered exactly the way i was looking for

Answer (score 3):

There are many strategies, but in general it traverses the object graph (by starting from special objects which are called GC roots) and marks those objects that it can find within the graph. Any object in the heap that hasn't been marked is essentially garbage since it is unreachable from any other object in the object graph.

For a more-detailed treatment, take a look at [Oracle's documentation on the JVM's garbage collector](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) and [this article](http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a hundred answers here but maybe none are simple--There are a lot of complicated ways to explain this :).  I'll give it a try so you can see it before this question is marked duplicate.

1. It takes things that it knows you "Want" like a visible window or an
   active thread.  There is a clearly specified list of these things in more complicated answers.
2. It makes a list of evertyhing these important points can possibly access.
3. It deletes everything else.